# one who says whatever men does is right / men can do this but not women

Tags: idioms

Similar to Male chauvinist (one who thinks men is superior), what is the word for a person who says, "Men can do this but not women" or "whatever a male does is correct"

Comment: When you make a request like this, it's also helpful to include an example sentence or dialogue.

Comment: Also indicate why *male chauvinist* is not appropriate.

Comment: Hi Em, for example, drinking, women should not drink. If the statement is generic like drinking is a bad habit then its fine. but they specify that women should not drink and they wont say anything about men drinking. Just an example.

Comment: Hi Jason, Male Chauvinist thinks, he is superior and always expect women to be under their control. Though my question sounds to the meaning of chauvinist, i am expecting more specific word. Hope my understanding is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that the term you're looking for is [**misogyny**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Misogyny):

> Misogyny is the hatred of, contempt for, or prejudice against women or girls. Misogyny is manifest in numerous ways, including social exclusion, sex discrimination, hostility, androcentrism, patriarchy, male privilege, belittling of women, violence against women, and sexual objectification. Misogyny can be found within sacred texts of religions, mythologies, and Western philosophies.

A person (typically a man) who has misogynistic views towards women would be called [**a misogynist**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/misogynist).

Answer (score 0):

Another term would be **sexist**.